# CSS keyframed animation jumpy in IE10

Tags: css, internet-explorer-10, css-animations, css-transforms, keyframe

I've created a simple, looping animation that uses the `translate` function to move elements left and right. This works elegantly in Chrome, Firefox and event starts off well in IE10, however when the animation reverses the elements jump.

I have created an example of the issue on CodePen, just open it up in IE10: http://codepen.io/anon/full/cxtza (updated)

I have attempted to mitigate the problem by hardcoding the keyframes 0%, 50% and 100% instead of `from/to` and using the `alternate` direction property, I've tried using `translateX` instead of 3D but so far no luck.

*Update*: The bug has been reported https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/785881/animated-transform-with-translate-and-percentage-value-jumps-ie10

Comment: Animation is jumpy on my Chrome to. Please, post the code here.

Comment: @i_like_robots Your pen looks identical in IE10 and Chrome for me. What am I missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### % transformations

The problem appears to occur when animating the `transform` property with `%` values. If you animate the `tranform` property with `px` values, it runs fine in IE10. Likewise, if you animate a different property like `margin-left` with `%` values, it runs fine.

IE doesn't appear to handle `%` values well when animating the `transform` property. I'd suggest either using a unit other than `%`, or animating a property other than `transform`.

**Example using px values**

[Updated demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Matt_Coughlin/WCC2K/2/)   (tested fine in IE10, Firefox, Chrome, Safari, and Opera)

```
@-webkit-keyframes pulse {
  from { -webkit-transform: translateX(0); }
  to   { -webkit-transform: translateX(100px); }
}
@-moz-keyframes pulse {
  from { -moz-transform: translateX(0); }
  to   { -moz-transform: translateX(100px); }
}
@keyframes pulse {
  from { transform: translateX(0); }
  to   { transform: translateX(100px); }
}

.blob {
    width: 320px;
    height: 320px;
    background: red;
    -webkit-animation: pulse 2s linear infinite alternate;
       -moz-animation: pulse 2s linear infinite alternate;
            animation: pulse 2s linear infinite alternate;
}
```

**Example using left margin**

[Updated demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Matt_Coughlin/GgJvq/2/)   (tested fine in IE10, Firefox, Chrome, Safari, and Opera)

```
@-webkit-keyframes pulse {
    from { margin-left: 0%; }
    to   { margin-left: 20%; }
}
@-moz-keyframes pulse {
    from { margin-left: 0%; }
    to   { margin-left: 20%; }
}
@keyframes pulse {
    from { margin-left: 0%; }
    to   { margin-left: 20%; }
}

.blob {
    width: 320px;
    height: 320px;
    background: red;
    -webkit-animation: pulse 2s linear infinite alternate;
       -moz-animation: pulse 2s linear infinite alternate;
            animation: pulse 2s linear infinite alternate;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your time in investigating this, it clearly points to a browser bug. For performance reasons I'd like to keep the animation on the GPU so I guess I'll have to run with CSS pixels for now rather than a relative unit (the problem also occurs with ems).

Comment: I noticed the same issue, is there any fix to this?

Comment: I wonder if there is coming a fix for this? still seems to be an issue in IE11?

Comment: This bug also occurs if you use IE11 and Win7 (it's fine for Win8 and Win10) and use em or % values for your keyframe animation. Again, using px solves the problem.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not helpful for bugs with ```rotate``` which only supports ```deg``` and not px values.

Comment: I find that animating transform using % is  slower than px on chrome - even today. (I also tried to fix the width of the container directly)